# How do I remove the parentheses in the python code below?

Tags: python, integer, asterisk

```
  x,y,z=1,2,3
print((x,y,z) * 2)
#the outpout is (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

how do I get the output to not include the ()

Is there a way, separately, to remove the commas?

Answer (score 1):

Unpack the `tuple` as separate `print` arguments, and you'll get it space-separated:

```
print(*(x,y,z) * 2)
```

You can then add the commas back in with a `sep` argument:

```
print(*(x,y,z) * 2, sep=', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

```
x,y,z=1,2,3
print(*((x,y,z) * 2))
```

will print out without parentheses.